# The problem about implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3' in android studio

Tags: android, okhttp

I just create a new project in Android Studio without doing anything,when I want to import 'Okhttp',the problem just like the following shows.
How can I solve the problem?
Thank you for your help!

the code

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3")
```

the problems

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.Could not find okhttp-4.9.3.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3).
```

Comment: I found that we can user a lower version to avoid this problem .

Comment: If you know the reason of the problem , please share it, thank you

Comment: check if you have any other dependency that includes an older version of okhttp inside it

Comment: It looks to be published fine https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.9.3

Perhaps you have a cached version of 4.9.2 and there is some other reason download is failing?

Answer (score 1):

check doc url https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.9.0/jar

version 4.9.0

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
```